# wordpress multisite > sub-sub-directory > wp-admin does not open

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have a multisite system running. With one sub-folder everything works perfectly. Fronend is at `domain.com/folder` and backend at `domain.com/folder/wp-admin`

But now I need `domain.com/folder/en/` and the Backend should be at `domain.com/folder/en/wp-admin` but it does not. I think the problem is somewhere in my `htaccess`.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Rule 1
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # Rule 2: uploaded files
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)*files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

    # Rule 3: add a trailing slash to "/wp-admin"
    # Note: This rule issues and redirect that will subsequently match Rule 5
    RewriteRule ^(([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)*)wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    # Rule 4: do nothing if URL is a file or directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rule 5: strip preceeding path from wp-(content|admin|includes) paths
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)*(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)*(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Does someone know this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?  I'm encountering a similar dilemma and not finding any documentation to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines on your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This does not change anything in my case. 
If I enter: https://domain.com/site-one/wp-admin/ the backend of site-one opens - everything works perfectly.

If I enter: https://domain.com/site-two/sub/wp-admin/ the backend of the main site ( same like https://domain.com/site-one/wp-admin/ ) opens. This is wrong.

In the fronend I also have an error. https://domain.com/site-two/sub/ returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong, but actually :

• your url is http(s)://mycustomurl/
• did u try to change to http(s)://mycustomurl/**en/** in Network site page configuration ?

Regards